# R: ess emacs, jump to function implementation/source

Tags: r, emacs, ess

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> lets me view documentation for a function at cursor's position. But what key sequence for me to view the source code of the function (i.e like the <kbd>F2</kbd> key in `Rstudio`)? I do not want to use the `debug` function yet.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> does the job.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. It only opens a new blank buffer.

Comment: Did you have the cursor on the function name, and Ess session started?